# React Native: RNUILib 5.30.0 in React-Native 0.65.1 wont build due to error

Tags: android, react-native

**Background:** I am trying to setup RNUILib on a react-native project but it wont build.
I followed the instructions from the official [guide](https://wix.github.io/react-native-ui-lib/getting-started/setup).

**Environment:** Android/Windows

**Here's my dependencies:**

```
@react-native-community/blur : 3.6.0
@react-native-community/datetimepicker : 3.5.2
@react-native-community/masked-view : 0.1.11
@react-native-community/netinfo : 6.0.1
@react-native-picker/picker : 1.16.7
@react-navigation/drawer : 6.1.4
@react-navigation/native : 6.0.2
react: 17.0.2
react-native: 0.65.1
react-native-gesture-handler : 1.10.3
react-native-reanimated : 2.3.0-alpha.2
react-native-safe-area-context : 3.3.0
react-native-screens : 3.6.0
react-native-ui-lib : 5.30.0
```

**Error log from `react-native run-android` command:**

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.6.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/eightbitlab/blurview/1.6.3/blurview-1.6.3.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/eightbitlab/blurview/1.6.3/blurview-1.6.3.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/vfvic/.m2/repository/com/eightbitlab/blurview/1.6.3/blurview-1.6.3.pom
       - file:/D:/_react-native/CBTracker2/node_modules/react-native/android/com/eightbitlab/blurview/1.6.3/blurview-1.6.3.pom
       - file:/D:/_react-native/CBTracker2/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/eightbitlab/blurview/1.6.3/blurview-1.6.3.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/eightbitlab/blurview/1.6.3/blurview-1.6.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-community_blur
```

As I have mentioned, I have performed all the steps in the Setup guide, including the linking of `@react-native-community/blur`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apparently, this is due to com.eightbitlab:blurview being only available from jcenter which is required by react-native-community_blur.

I've added `jcenter()` in my build.gradle file and it's now working fine.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not proper solution as jcenter will be off soon https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown

Comment: True. It's just the only workaround I found. I removed the accepted answer mark for the good of all.

Comment: This is a satisfactory solution for now I'd assume as https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration confirms (as well as the update posted in the link posted above) that they've decided to keep it open indefinitely in a read only state - so whilst waiting for the upstream depdency to be migrated over it won't hurt to leave the jcenter call in your repositories

Comment: this solution works with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/blur installation as well

Answer (score 1):

late but hope it will help someone, update android/build.gradle like below

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ....rest

        jcenter() {
            content {
                includeModule("com.eightbitlab", "blurview")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is needed now when jcenter is gone

Answer (score 0):

According officials, just try https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-blur/issues/444

Answer (score 0):

update `react-native.config.js` file If you are using this package on iOS only

```
module.exports = {
   ...

  dependencies: {
    '@react-native-community/blur': {
      platforms: {
        android: null,
      },
    },
  },

 ...
};
```